# ListBox selection change does postback even though AutoPostBack is set to false for the ListBox

Tags: asp.net

The problem is described in the title. It does postbacking also when I specifically set AutoPostBack property of the ListBox to false, though it should be like that by default.
ListBox selection mode is set to multiple.

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066977/firing-selectedindexchanged-event-but-the-listboxs-autopostback-property-is-f) but with a different background.

What am I missing? Is this some well known issue?

Thank you for replying,
please tell if you need the exact code

EDIT:

Here's the aspx page. Codebehind is much larger, since this page is the target of redirection, please tell if you need additional info from there.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ReportsPreviewViewAddParams.aspx.cs" Inherits="Admin_ReportsPreviewViewAddParams" %>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">

        <asp:HiddenField ID="SqlSelect" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="SqlColumnSize" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="SqlGroup" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="SqlOrder" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="PageSize" runat="server" />
        <asp:HiddenField ID="SumColumns" runat="server" />

        <asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterInput" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="OnRepeaterItemDataBound" >
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table>
                <tr><th>
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelHeader" runat="server" Text='<%# Webcom.Configurator.Core.MLPersistentManager.GetKeyValue("Admin.Reports.EnterParams") %>' />
                </th></tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxValueOne" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" />
                        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxControlOne" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="LabelOperatorOne" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="LabelColumnName" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Label ID="LabelOperatorTwo" runat="server" /></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxValueTwo" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" />
                        <asp:ListBox ID="ListBoxControlTwo" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

        <asp:Button ID="buttonSubmit" runat="server" Visible="true" OnClick="OnSubmit" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Cpba Show us your code.

Comment: code monster hungry, give me some code. nom nom nom.

Comment: just a sec. I'm having a problem with pasting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repeater does not have a way of tracking autopostbacks that happen from controls within the repeater. This may offer you a clue:

[Handling autopostbacks within a repeater](http://weblogs.asp.net/rternier/archive/2006/04/04/handling-autopostbacks-within-a-repeater-checkbox-style.aspx)

You could try initializing the AutoPostBack property early in the code-behind page life-cycle, perhaps in Page Load method (after page controls have been created):

```
ListBox ListBoxControlOne = (ListBox)RepeaterInput.FindControl("ListBoxControlOne");
ListBoxControlOne.AutoPostBack = false;
```

Comment: I've tried this (only with quotation marks inside of FindControl()) and I'm getting null reference exception. I expected that - shouldn't "ListBoxControlOne" be reachable only from an RepeaterItem ? Am I right?
I also tried to move the repeater data binding to init phase or add setting AutoPostBack to false in OnItemDataBound handler, but nothing works.
Thanks

Comment: I think whatever you try here will be a hack. Did you play with the page autopostback property?

Comment: Nope. I didn't know Page class has one.
The only thing specific about this repeater is the source it's bound to. I use the other repeater from PreviousPage (since the page is use to redirect to) and extract some of its items (by some criteria) to a collection. Then I bind this page repeater to the collection and in OnItemDataBound I'm setting its item's control properties related to the DataItem (a RepeaterItem also as I said). Maybe that has something to do with this?

Comment: I doubt it. I would check for all ListBoxes and set the autopostback property to false in the code-behind; only thing I can think of. You may need to grapple with the life-cycle a bit. You could also try adding the ListBoxes programmatically?

Comment: Huh!
I did items iteration with setting AutoPostBack to false, right after DataBind() method (all in the Page_Load method) and it worked.
But it didn't work when doing it from OnItemDataBound. 
It isn't logical, is it?